# Remove shadow from joomla website

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using Joomla! 3.4.5 and I just saw a tag named shadow when inspecting the page.

```
#shadow-root (open)
<shadow>
    <head>
    #comment
    <body>
</shadow>
<style></style>
```

This tag is associated with some style which hide some elements on my page.

I don't know what is this tag and where it come from.

What does this shadow tag means and how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed to be there, as part of the "Shadow DOM".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Shadow

> The HTML `<shadow>` element is used as a shadow DOM insertion point. You might use it if you have created multiple shadow roots under a shadow host. It is not useful in ordinary HTML. It is used with Web Components.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

> Web Components is a set of cutting edge standards that:
>
> Make it possible to build widgets
> …which can be reused reliably
> …and which won’t break pages if the next version of the component changes internal implementation details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case the problem was the AdBlock extension of google chrome.
I just disable it and my page is shown correctly